# Unable to archive with Xcode 11 GM

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I am currently unable to archive my app using Xcode 11 GM, seed 1 and 2.

I want to upload my new iOS 13 build to App Store Connect but am unable to because of this issue.

The archive always gets stuck on task number 911 when archiving, this is when it says it is building Realm or Charts. The same happens when building using `fastlane gym` except it gets stuck much earlier when compiling `nanopb-vers.m`

So far I have tried suggestions from people facing a similar issue with no luck:

- Changing compilation mode
- Changing optimisation level
- Adding a custom building setting (LD_VERIFY_BITCODE = NO)
- Using the legacy build system
- Using fastlane
- Removing `armv7` from supported architectures
- Setting debug information format to just `DWARF`

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Don't bother: you cannot upload any archive to App Store Connect using Xcode 11 GM anyway. It will abort with the message that the archive was created using beta software.

Comment: Hi @LinusGeffarth thanks for the comment, but it doesn't solve the problem.